# macos with vscode ctrl+f2 does not work on macos as expected

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using a macos and regularly use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+f2 to view the time when working in full screen mode.  However this does not work when working with VSCode.  Initially I thought it might be bound to some keyboard shortcut in VSCode itself which it is capturing but could not find such shortcut.  Does anyone know how to get this working as expected and show the titlebar as the standard behavior when using other apps on the macos.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is related to Electron-based applications like VSCode, Azure Data Studio and Microsoft Teams. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)

It doesn't happen with bundled macOS applications, Chrome or Office applications.
So, it seems to be related to the Electron infrastructure and should be solved at that level. You can report the issue to their GitHub repository at https://github.com/electron/electron